# Jquery could not select elem by id

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="button" id="elem" value="Search">

<script>
  var elem1 = $("#elem");
  elem1.onclick = hello;

  function hello() {
    alert("hello");
  }
</script>
```

I don't understand why couldn't I select id element by Jquery, how I could do with JS document.getElementById

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `elem1` is a jQuery object, It doesn't have `onclick` property. You can use either of these method to bind the event handler.

Here, `[0]` will get the underlying DOM element then you can use `onclick`

```
elem1[0].onclick = hello;
```

or use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the event handler

```
elem1.on('click', hello);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `elem1` is a jQuery object and `onclick` is works with DOM object. Either get DOM object and set `onclick` or use [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method to bind event handler to jQuery object.

```
elem1[0].onclick = hello;
// or      
elem1.click(hello);
```